# How do I add styles using CKEditor Custom drop down plugin

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, ckeditor

So I added this plugin which gives me the code to have a dropdown menu on my CKeditor toolbar, which holds all my styles which apply themselves on click. See code:

```
CKEDITOR.plugins.add( 'tokens',
{   
   requires : ['richcombo'], //, 'styles' ],
   init : function( editor )
   {
      var config = editor.config,
         lang = editor.lang.format;

      // Gets the list of tags from the settings.
      var tags = []; //new Array();
      //this.add('value', 'drop_text', 'drop_label');
      tags[0]=["[contact_name]", "Name", "Name"];
      tags[1]=["[contact_email]", "email", "email"];
      tags[2]=["[contact_user_name]", "User name", "User name"];

      // Create style objects for all defined styles.

      editor.ui.addRichCombo( 'tokens',
         {
            label : "Insert tokens",
            title :"Insert tokens",
            voiceLabel : "Insert tokens",
            className : 'cke_format',
            multiSelect : false,

            panel :
            {
               css : [ config.contentsCss, CKEDITOR.getUrl( editor.skinPath + 'editor.css' ) ],
               voiceLabel : lang.panelVoiceLabel
            },

            init : function()
            {
               this.startGroup( "Tokens" );
               //this.add('value', 'drop_text', 'drop_label');
               for (var this_tag in tags){
                  this.add(tags[this_tag][0], tags[this_tag][1], tags[this_tag][2]);
               }
            },

            onClick : function( value )
            {         
               editor.focus();
               editor.fire( 'saveSnapshot' );
               editor.insertHtml(value);
               editor.fire( 'saveSnapshot' );
            }
         });
   }
});
```

So what this code does is just insert whatever is in the tags ["[contact_name"] so when you click on "Name" in the dropdown, it just drops [contact_name] in the text editor. I want to know how I make each tag a specific function which adds css to whatever is selected in the text editor. For example have a function called 'Red Font' and whatever < p > font exists it turns red.

Comment: Any new development for your plugin?

Comment: Did you ever figure this out - need to make mine wider and style the fonts?

Answer (score 0):

```
CKEDITOR.replace( 'editorId', {
    extraPlugins: 'tokens'
});
```

add this code and replace the editor id with your editor id.
that's it.

Answer (score 0):

```
CKEDITOR.replace( 'editor', { 
    extraPlugins: 'tokens' // why tokens see below
});
```

because you have given

```
CKEDITOR.plugins.add( 'tokens',
{   
    requires : ['richcombo']
    ..
```